# I am creating a multi-threaded java application which simulates a persons spending pattern

Tags: java, multithreading, timer, simulation

```
/**
 *
 * 
 * A small class to handle deposits and withdrawls from a bank account
 * 
 */
package spendingsimulation;

//import java.util.Random;

public class BankAccount 
{
    public int accountBalance;
    public int incomeAmt;
    public BankAccount()
    {
        accountBalance = 0 ;
        //incomeAmt = 0;
    }

    public void deposit(int addAmount, String name)
    {
        // the 'name' argument holds the name of the source of this credit 

        accountBalance+=addAmount ;
        System.out.println(name + " added " + addAmount) ;
        System.out.println("Account balance is now standing at " + accountBalance);
    }

    public void withdraw(int takeAmount, String name)
    {
        // the 'name' argument holds the name of the bill being paid

        accountBalance-=takeAmount ;
        System.out.println(name + " took " + takeAmount) ;
        System.out.println("Account balance is now standing at " + accountBalance);
    }

    public int getBalance()
    {
        return accountBalance ;
    }

    //@Override
    /*public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            deposit(incomeAmt, incomeS1);
            getBalance();
            Thread.sleep(100) ;
        } // End of try block
        catch(InterruptedException ex)
        {
            System.out.println(typeOfUtility + " Terminated early") ;
        } // End of Catch clause

        System.out.println(typeOfUtility + " has finished") ;
    }  // End of method run()
    */


} // End of class BankAccount
```

---

```
package spendingsimulation;

import java.lang.Thread ;

public class SpendMain {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        System.out.println("Viewing expenditure");

        // Incoming payments
        Thread incomeS1 = new Thread(new Incomming("Wage Recieved", 2000, 1000) );
        Thread incomeS2 = new Thread(new Incomming("Interest Recieved", 10, 4000) );

        // Outgoing costs
        Thread outgoingS1 = new Thread(new Consumables("Oil Bill", 250, 3000)) ;
        Thread outgoingS2 = new Thread(new Consumables("Food Bill", 600, 1000)) ;
        Thread outgoingS3 = new Thread(new Consumables("Electricity Bill", 50, 1000)) ;
        Thread outgoingS4 = new Thread(new Consumables("Entertrainment Bill", 400, 1000)) ;
        Thread outgoingS5 = new Thread(new Consumables("Shopping Bill", 200, 1000)) ;

        System.out.println("Expenditure commencing") ;


        // Get the threads going
        //Incomming
        incomeS1.start();
        incomeS2.start();

        // Outgoing
        outgoingS1.start();
        outgoingS2.start();
        outgoingS3.start();
        outgoingS4.start();
        outgoingS5.start();


        System.out.println("Expenditure is now underway.") ; 


    }
}
```

---

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package spendingsimulation;

import java.util.Random;

/**
 *
 * @author B00533474
 */
public class Incomming implements Runnable {

    //private int workingTime ;
   private String typeOfUtility ;
   // private Random randGen ;
    //private int incomingAmt;

    public Incomming(String name, int addAmount, int time){
        typeOfUtility = name ;

      //  randGen = new Random();
        //workingTime = randGen.nextInt(10000) ; // Up to 10 seconds

      //  outgoingAmt = amt;
    }

    //@Override
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            System.out.println(typeOfUtility + " has come into the account");
            System.out.println(" The balance on the account is now: ");
            //this.getBalance();
            Thread.sleep(1000) ;
        } // End of try block
        catch(InterruptedException ex)
        {
            System.out.println(typeOfUtility + " Terminated early") ;
        } // End of Catch clause

        System.out.println(typeOfUtility + " has finished") ;
    }  // End of method run()

}
```

---

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package spendingsimulation;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Timer;

/**
 *
 * @author B00533474
 */
public class Consumables implements Runnable {

    private int workingTime ;
    private String typeOfUtility ;
    private Random randGen ;
    private int incomeAmt;


    Consumables(String name, int amt, int time) {
        typeOfUtility = name ;
        randGen = new Random();
        workingTime = randGen.nextInt(10000) ; // Up to 10 seconds
        incomeAmt = amt;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Timer myTimer = new Timer();

    }

}
```

My problem is that I do not know how many, or what class the run() method should be in and how to access and use the Bank Account class correctly. I am also unsure if how to use the timer class, I want each second to represent one week. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is there anything you have done to try to solve this problem? We will be more willing to answer your question if you tell us what you have tried so far. (Helpful links for asking better questions: [ask], [FAQ])

Comment: Also, your question has quite a bit of code. For better help sooner, post a [SSCCE (link)](http://sscce.org).

Comment: I would suggest that you begin by making the bank account thread safe before you move onto whacking it with threads. Hint, `Integer` is not thread safe. The JVM makes no guarantees that even the write is atomic. And, further, without `volatile` other threads are unlikely to see writes anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a trivial example.

You have a `Balance` class which holds an `AtomicInteger` that is the current balance.

You the have three kinds of runnables, `Income`, `Expenditure` and `Statement` - these are self explanatory.

The meat of the method is the `main` method. This uses a `ScheduledExectorService` to schedule different income events to happen as different rates. The comments explain what's what.

Finally we have a task that shuts the whole lot down after a year - this can easily be changed or removed, in which case it will run for ever.

You have examples of both repeated tasks at an interval and tasks that run once after a delay (the shutdown task).

This implementation has no error handling - tasks will fail silently; but there shouldn't be any reason for tasks to fair given their simplicity.

You may need to use a `BigDecimal` if you want to introduce non-integer values, this is more complicated as you will need to `synchronize` manually.

```
static final class Balance {

    private final AtomicInteger balance;

    public Balance(int initalBalance) {
        this.balance = new AtomicInteger(initalBalance);
    }

    public void debit(final int amount) {
        balance.addAndGet(-amount);
    }

    public void credit(final int amount) {
        balance.addAndGet(amount);
    }

    public int balance() {
        return balance.get();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "£" + balance.get();
    }
}

static final class Income implements Runnable {

    private final Balance balance;
    private final int income;

    public Income(Balance balance, int income) {
        this.balance = balance;
        this.income = income;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        balance.credit(income);
    }
}

static final class Expenditure implements Runnable {

    private final Balance balance;
    private final int cost;

    public Expenditure(Balance balance, int cost) {
        this.balance = balance;
        this.cost = cost;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        balance.debit(cost);
    }
}

static final class Statement implements Runnable {

    private final Balance balance;

    public Statement(Balance balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Your balance this month is " + balance.toString());
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    final Balance balance = new Balance(1000);
    final ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    //print balance  - monthly
    executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Statement(balance), 0, 4, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    //income - monthly
    executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Income(balance, 1000), 0, 4, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    //rent - monthly
    executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Expenditure(balance, 500), 4, 4, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    //food - weekly
    executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Expenditure(balance, 50), 1, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    //shutdown after a year
    executorService.schedule(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            executorService.shutdown();
        }
    }, 52, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help everyone, I've got the application running now with timed intervals using the `ScheduledExecutorService`

The only problem is that the application runs for 6 minutes. Where it should only run for 52 seconds? I tried this: @Boris_the_Spider).

`//shutdown after a 52 secs
    executorService.schedule(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            accountBalance.getBalance();
            executorService.shutdown();
        }
    }, 52, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}`

But it still ran for 6 minutes? Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Update your code - it's probably to do with a long-running task.